# Select key column from data as null if it doesn't exist in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My Dataframe (df) is structured as follows:

```
root
 |-- val1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- val2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- val3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I have two sample records as follows:

```
+------+------+-----------------------------------+
| val1 | val2 |               val3                |
+------+------+-----------------------------------+
|  A   |  a   |     {k1: A1, k2: A2, k3: A3}      |
+------+------+-----------------------------------+
|  B   |  b   |                {k3: B3}           |
+------+------+-----------------------------------+
```

I'm trying to select data from this as follows:

df.select(val1,val2,val3.k1,val3.k2,val3.k3)

And I want my output to look like:

```
+------+------+---------+---------+---------+
| val1 | val2 |    k1   |   k2    |   k3    |
+------+------+---------+---------+---------+
|  A   |  a   |   A1    |   A2    |   A3    |
+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  B   |  b   |  NULL   |  NULL   |   B3    |
+------+------+-----------------------------+
```

But since I don't have the keys k1 and k2 for all records, the select statement throws an error. How do I solve this? I'm relatively new to pyspark.

Comment: Can you show what kind of transformations you have done on this dataframe before reaching this state? ```val3``` is an array of structs which doesn't seem right and I can't replicate creating the same schema. Generally, looking at your data val3 should be either a map or a struct

Comment: I'm sorry, val3 is an array, the data is listed as follows:

+------+------+-----------------------------------+
| val1 | val2 |               val3                |
+------+------+-----------------------------------+
|  A   |  a   |     [[k1: A1], [k2: A2], [k3: A3]]      |
+------+------+-----------------------------------+
|  B   |  b   |                [[k3: B3]]           |
+------+------+-----------------------------------+

Comment: I'm basically looking to explode the array into columns in pyspark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use

```
df.selectExpr('val3.*')
```

Let me know if this works